# A "scuffle" versus a "fight to the death"?

Tags: grammar

I want to describe an event where an intense fight broke out:

> "It was not so much a scuffle, as a fight to the death."

Did I word this sentence correctly?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's fine. It's common phrasing.

https://www.google.com/search?q=%22not+so+much+a+%2a+as+a+%2a%22

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

> "It was not so much a scuffle, but turned out a fight to death."